# for loops in r to create a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PRmz.png)I want to create a 10 by 8 matrix from two matrices again with dimensions 10 by 8 by using for loops.

I have matrices a and e and I want to save the results of below code to a matrix. But when I run the code, the matrix chi is an empty matrix except with the last row of the last column. I am kind of newby to R, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
chi <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 8, byrow = T)
i <- nrow(a)
j <- ncol(a)
k <- nrow(e)
l <- ncol(e)
m <- nrow(chi)
n <- ncol(chi)
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
 for (j in 1:ncol(a)) {
   for (k in 1:nrow(e)) {
     for (l in 1:ncol(e))
    chi[m, n] <- ((a[i, j] - e[k, l]) ^ 2 / (e[k, l] * (1 - e[k, l])))
  }
 }

 }
```

Comment: You should show `a` and `e` to make your problem reproducible. Also the expected output would be helpful.

Comment: m and n are never incremented in the loops, they are just set the nrow and ncol of the chi matrix.

Comment: Thanks @markus, I have added a picture of e matrix. I want chi matrix is also similar to e matrix.

Comment: Thanks @Dave2e, any idea how to solve the problem in my code you mentioned??

Comment: You should provide test data for a & e (use the output from `dput` function) and what the expected results should be.  I am not understanding the expected results from code's logic in order to debug the multiple loops.

Answer (score 1):

Reconsider using *any* nested `for` loops as you can simply run matrix algebra since all inputs, *a* and *e*, are equal length objects:

```
chi <- ((a - e) ^ 2 / (e * (1 - e)))
```

With your nested `for` loop approach, your attempted matrix cell assignment is overwritten with each inner loop pass and only the very last instance is saved.

To demonstrate, consider the following random matrices (seeded for reproducibility):

```
set.seed(1162018)
a <- matrix(runif(800), nrow = 10, ncol = 8)
e <- matrix(runif(800), nrow = 10, ncol = 8)
```

With following output:

```
chi2 <- ((a - e) ^ 2 / (e * (1 - e)))
chi2
#               [,1]        [,2]        [,3]         [,4]       [,5]        [,6]         [,7]         [,8]
#  [1,]  1.090516287 5.314965506  0.30221649 4.3078030566 0.08185310  0.33991625 7.475638e-01 7.136321e+01
#  [2,]  0.339472596 0.037831564  1.00181544 0.0075194551 0.27228312 20.74823838 2.308509e-04 1.264312e-04
#  [3,]  0.001493967 0.009102797 17.76508355 0.0318190760 0.08133848  0.90538852 1.425952e-01 3.600838e-02
#  [4,] 25.941857200 2.182678801  0.52170472 0.5485710933 0.57015681  0.09332506 2.631002e-01 4.897862e-01
#  [5,]  4.341993499 0.075724451  0.03409925 0.0058830640 0.15290151  0.83227284 2.982630e+02 2.615268e-01
#  [6,]  0.327661207 0.058150213  0.17328257 0.3161902785 4.48620227  0.14685330 2.996204e+00 1.888419e+01
#  [7,]  0.456397833 1.446942556  0.51597191 0.2051742161 0.20440765  0.58169351 5.345522e+00 1.320896e-03
#  [8,] 12.844776005 0.753941152  0.36425134 0.0003481929 0.34011118  2.38649404 1.082046e-01 1.817180e-01
#  [9,]  0.042779101 0.119540004  1.41313002 0.1262586599 0.36583013  1.76476721 1.353301e+00 1.670491e-01
# [10,]  4.729182008 5.257386394  0.62181731 0.0000251250 0.32324943  0.08491841 6.627723e+00 2.127289e+00
```

Notice the very first, second, all the way to last elements of `chi2` is consistent to your original formula as seen with using only single values. The `all.equal()` demonstrates no value difference between scientific notation or not.

```
((a[1, 1] - e[1, 1]) ^ 2 / (e[1, 1] * (1 - e[1, 1])))    
# [1] 1.090516

((a[1, 2] - e[1, 2]) ^ 2 / (e[1, 2] * (1 - e[1, 2])))
# [1] 1.090516
# ...
((a[10, 8] - e[10, 8]) ^ 2 / (e[10, 8] * (1 - e[10, 8])))
# [1] 2.127289

all.equal(2.127289e+00, 2.127289)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

**Incorrect For Loop Processing**

However, adjusting your `for` loop to use `chi[i,j]` assignment which does yield values but on closer look does **not** accurately align to your original formula:

```
chi <- matrix(nrow = 10, ncol = 8, byrow = T)

i <- nrow(a)
j <- ncol(a)
k <- nrow(e)
l <- ncol(e)
m <- nrow(chi)
n <- ncol(chi)
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(a)) {
    for (k in 1:nrow(e)) {
      for (l in 1:ncol(e))
        chi[i,j] <- ((a[i, j] - e[k, l]) ^ 2 / (e[k, l] * (1 - e[k, l])))          
    }
  }      
}

chi
#              [,1]       [,2]        [,3]       [,4]       [,5]        [,6]       [,7]      [,8]
#  [1,] 3.409875713 1.91797098 0.983457185 0.72023148 0.96731753 0.047236836 2.20811240 0.6073649
#  [2,] 0.011756997 2.96049899 3.614632753 1.30476270 2.49116488 0.074379894 1.01941080 0.3796867
#  [3,] 2.061628776 0.03227113 0.691592758 2.58226782 0.17603261 4.377353084 1.07957101 0.9584883
#  [4,] 5.477395731 0.07409188 5.287871705 1.86472765 2.02597697 0.078780553 6.20319269 2.6099405
#  [5,] 4.342937737 3.57579681 1.016981597 2.83351392 1.11431922 0.083484410 0.08412765 0.5525810
#  [6,] 0.008175703 2.63310577 0.005053893 3.69703754 0.05993078 0.004768071 5.92075341 4.2435415
#  [7,] 1.051921956 0.31217144 5.624012725 0.90161687 0.43301151 0.156739757 0.72284317 1.2243496
#  [8,] 4.941310521 4.85504735 0.021515999 3.66512027 0.08358373 3.603038468 0.38618455 6.1389345
#  [9,] 0.559136535 5.08204325 2.999036687 2.72726724 5.99168376 0.319859158 0.59398961 3.6221932
# [10,] 0.001668949 2.97353267 4.703763876 0.04979429 5.31715581 0.053267595 2.09966809 2.1272893
```

Here, the `for` loop returns only the very last instance since `chi[i,j]` is overwritten multiple times during loop. As a result, ALL elements of `chi` matrix uses the **last** element of *e*:

```
((a[1, 1] - e[10, 8]) ^ 2 / (e[10, 8] * (1 - e[10, 8])))
# [1] 3.409876

((a[1, 2] - e[10, 8]) ^ 2 / (e[10, 8] * (1 - e[10, 8])))
# [1] 1.917971
# ...
((a[10, 8] - e[10, 8]) ^ 2 / (e[10, 8] * (1 - e[10, 8])))
# [1] 2.127289
```

Conversely, with using `chi[k,l]` for assignment in loop.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(a)) {
  for (j in 1:ncol(a)) {
    for (k in 1:nrow(e)) {
      for (l in 1:ncol(e))
        chi[k,l] <- ((a[i, j] - e[k, l]) ^ 2 / (e[k, l] * (1 - e[k, l])))          
    }
  }    
}

chi
#               [,1]         [,2]         [,3]        [,4]        [,5]        [,6]         [,7]         [,8]
#  [1,] 5.649285e-01 5.813300e+00  0.035949545 10.14845208 0.002533313 0.405749651  0.711058301 2.592142e+01
#  [2,] 7.481556e+00 4.531135e-05  0.455696004  0.09284383 0.192074706 4.178867177  0.105489574 3.541626e-01
#  [3,] 4.953702e-04 6.703029e+00 41.109139456  0.08957573 1.511080005 0.254656165  0.004840752 2.805246e-01
#  [4,] 1.152237e+01 2.556255e-02  0.018652264  0.65975403 0.515919955 0.280219679  0.124379946 7.777978e-01
#  [5,] 2.126765e+00 5.356927e-01  0.251885418  0.06540162 0.008580900 0.003271672 41.259025738 2.963719e-06
#  [6,] 1.401345e-01 1.603721e-02  0.334385097  0.05865054 0.622973490 0.608273911  0.888928067 1.046868e+01
#  [7,] 1.018507e-01 1.756129e-01  0.005676374  0.72309875 0.011666290 0.314863595 12.420604213 7.778975e-02
#  [8,] 6.082752e+00 1.250805e-01  0.287099891  0.17209992 0.050136187 1.339028574  1.059674334 2.627769e-01
#  [9,] 8.005223e-02 9.260464e-02  2.823995704  0.04935770 0.020361815 0.258144647  0.275514317 9.392584e-03
# [10,] 4.952038e-01 3.870331e+00  0.089420009  1.05729955 0.002429084 0.349966871  6.702385325 2.127289e+00
```

As a result, ALL matrix elements uses the **last** values of *a*:

```
((a[10, 8] - e[1, 1]) ^ 2 / (e[1, 1] * (1 - e[1, 1])))
# [1] 0.5649285
all.equal(5.649285e-01, 0.5649285)
# [1] TRUE

((a[10, 8] - e[1, 2]) ^ 2 / (e[1, 2] * (1 - e[1, 2])))
# [1] 5.8133
all.equal(5.813300e+00, 5.8133)
# [1] TRUE
# ...
((a[10, 8] - e[10, 8]) ^ 2 / (e[10, 8] * (1 - e[10, 8])))
# [1] 2.127289
```

Comment: Wow Thanks Parfait for such a detailed answer. Thanks so much, appreciate it!